# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in simple html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

why this error is showing in my simple html form, I want to get xml data in my simple form to show news on my webpage, but this error is showing continuously, please help

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=Nigeria&hl=en-PK&gl=PK&ceid=PK:en",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function(xml) {
          console.log(xml)

      }
  });
```

Comment: that's because `https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=Nigeria&hl=en-PK&gl=PK&ceid=PK:en` doesn't allow [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) ... *(CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to tell browsers to give a web application running at one origin, access to selected resources from a different origin. A web application executes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource that has a different origin (domain, protocol, or port) from its own.*

Comment: Thanks... is there any solution for this?? I want to get data

Comment: make the request from your **server** - i.e. the browser makes a request to **your** server, then **your** server borrows the data from `news.google.com` and returns the data to the client

Answer (score 0):

This is because of CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing) policy implemented by browsers. Which means browsers doesn't allow certain requests to be sent from a domain to another domain. However this is not applicable to all type of requests.

Check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Examples_of_access_control_scenarios) to understand what all requests come under this policy

Inorder to make this work , the other server, in your case `https://news.google.com`, have to setup in such a way that it allows cross domain requests. This is achieved by servers telling the browser that it is ready to accept cross domain requests from your domain, by adding certain cors related headers. One such is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. But I am afraid you can't do it since you aren't the one managing this server.

**Work-Around**

Use your backend to send the request to google. So that your xhr request calls your server and your server calls google. No browser No Cors.

> xhr---> `yourdomain.com/news/get`---> `someotherdomain.com/news/get`

Comment: thanks for you time.. is there any solution exist to overcome thi??

Comment: This has to be setup in google servers, no. Since this is a browser policy, clients other than browsers dont mind this. So you can make this request to google from your backend itself and use that data in the js. So your js request will be routed to your domain only. still you get the data you want

Answer (score 0):

It is up to the server that has the resource to allow cross origin access.

Probably there is API for what you are trying to do. API gets implemented by the resource owner and provides controlled access.

Or you can use RSS if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

What you could potentially do is run your requests through a CORS proxy. For example:

```
  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=Nigeria&hl=en-PK&gl=PK&ceid=PK:en",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {
          console.log(xml)
      }
  });
```

You can see that this works by simply pasting this code snippet into the console.

This essentially bypasses the CORS issues for you. I would only recommend using this hosted version if you don't have a lot of traffic, otherwise you should host your own version of the CORS proxy.